# How do I let mobile users view the non-mobile version of my site if I have a redirect?

Tags: cookies, asp-classic, mobile-website

Utilizing the classic ASP code found on http://detectmobilebrowser.com/ I have mobile browsers being automatically redirected to the much more lean and optimized mobile version of my site.

However, if a mobile user would rather view the full site, I have a link in the footer to take them there. Unfortunately, when they go back to the main site the mobile detect script kicks in and redirects them again.

How do I stop this from happening? My first thought was using a cookie, but I'm not familiar with the process involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do it with query string such as default.asp?redirect=0 then with if-else i only run dedection script when there is no redirect=0

Comment: That works on the first landing page. But then once the user tries to browse other pages on the site, they run into the redirect script again because it's on every page. And every link on the site won't have "redirect=0" attached to it. So they'll just get kicked right back to the mobile version.

Is having the mobile redirect on every page bad practice though? At first it seems like overkill, but I don't want mobile users to search for my site and end up on a sub page that doesn't have the redirect.

Comment: then i guess you would need to have some sort of rewrite rule on iis level

Answer (score 0):

On the mobile landing page, when the user clicks "continue to the desktop" link, the server set a cookie to flag the user wants to see the desktop site. Then for all the request, if the cookie is there, the server just let the request go the the desktop site. Otherwise redirect to the mobile site.

Sample code is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj553508.aspx